# Need help Regarding Vectors in c++;

Tags: c++, vector

I initialized a vector like

```
vector<vector<int>> A;
```

and the used the following loop for random input in vector.

n in the following code represents number of elements in a square matrix.

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            
            A[i][j] = rand() % 10;
            cout << A[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
```

but my program stops as soon it enter the 2nd for loop, Why?

Comment: Can we see what 'n' is please. That probably has something to do with why your loops are stopping.

Comment: What we have here is simple undefined behavior, from accessing a vector outside of its size.  You probably want to use `.push_back()`.

Comment: You set the outer vector up to contain 0 elements which means you end up with undefined behaviour when trying to access any element via `operator[]`. It's very likely that this produces a segfault, since usually the backing array is simply null unless you cause the vector to grow a size greater than 0 elements.

Comment: You also need to make sure you're setting the size of your vector before you use the '[]' operator. That operator will not add things to your vector, for that use 'push_back()'. The size of the vector can also be set in the constructor or through a call to 'resize()'.

Comment: Works on my machine.  Maybe you should use `A.at(i).at(j)` and see if that is illuminating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, you must specify the size of your vectors before using the `[]` operator. Otherwise, your vectors will have zero size and any index you give will be out of range. Constructing with a size is easily done:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> A(n, std::vector<int>(n));
```

This line of code uses a [`std::vector` constructor overload](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) that accepts a size and a value. The value is an instance of the inner vector type, constructed using another constructor overload that takes just the size and zero-initializes the member. This gives you a vector of `n` vectors of `n` integers.

With that, the following code works:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    const int n = 10;
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> A(n, std::vector<int>(n));

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            A[i][j] = rand() % 10;
            std::cout << A[i][j] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

And produces output similar to:

```
3 3 2 9 0 8 2 6 6 9 
1 1 3 5 8 3 0 6 9 2 
7 7 2 8 0 3 9 2 4 9 
1 7 0 4 5 0 4 0 2 4 
3 1 0 6 6 1 9 7 5 1 
0 4 4 5 9 0 7 6 3 4 
4 0 9 0 6 2 2 3 0 9 
9 5 5 9 7 9 7 4 6 9 
6 4 3 5 7 6 9 4 2 5 
3 8 1 0 0 7 5 6 3 1
```

In fact, I get that same output every run because there is no `srand()` call.

Comment: A note about leaving out trhe call to `srand`: This is actually helpful while testing. You can play around with the algorithm and see how your changes  play out with the exact same random numbers every time. When you think you've knocked out all of the bugs, add in the `srand` call with a fixed seed. Play around with a few different seeds to make sure you still don't have any bugs, and if you do, you can keep running the seed over and over again until you solve those bugs. When you're really confident, then randomize the seed and see if you're still bug-free.

Comment: 'srand( )' has not been called as is was still writing the logic and don't want the answer to  differ on each run.

Answer (score 2):

you didnt use the `push_back()` function

while we generate a vector , unless u give it a size , it is emtpy

so you could eithier use the `push_back` function or give it a size

code for pushing back

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        
        A[i].push_back(rand() % 10);
        cout << A[i][j] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```